# Can I have wildcard domains on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I need to have true wildcard domains.  I would like to use App Engine if possible, if not I would be interested to see if google had a different solution.

Can I have a wildcard domain like `*.mydomain.com` that accepts all sub domains without any hardcoding involved.  My goal is to let my users dynamically spin up their own subdomains without my direct intervention.  So I would rather not have to put the in a .yml file or any other whitelist.

How can I do this with app engine?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a wildcard domain, as `*.mydomain.com` that you mentioned, in the `dispatch.yaml` file. As per the documentation [Wildcard Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards), you just need to add the wildcard domain on this file and App Engine will do to the rerouting for you of all domains used to your `mydomain.com`.

On this other answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards), you can find another option as well and also more details on how to configure wildcards on App Engine. :)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: I don't suppose you remember from that far back, but I notice your second link was similar to the first, I assume there's been a copy-paste issue.